Are companies liable for firmware updates that brick devices?
Are companies generally liable for negligence when they provide user updatable firmware updates that consistently break products?
Sony’s latest update has been pulled after cameras no longer turn on.
One off issues happen, but this seems to be a recurring problem for them.
I think if I have dug deeper I could find a couple more instances of this happening in the past two years with the same cameras. The self-reports I’ve seen indicate that Sony’s position is the liability lies on the consumer for repair costs by Sony.
The firmware updates pages don’t specify a risk of the camera becoming inoperable. Instead, the only note even somewhat related is the generic improvement item:

Improves the functionality and operational stability of the camera

The limited warranty has the generic arbitration clause and carve-out for small claims court provisions but doesn’t appear to disclaim liability for firmware updates that Sony provides.
Update: The related questions aren’t quite relevant:

The linked Samsung question provides two key differences: a voluntary recall and bricking devices to avoid a real possibility of physical harm.

The second question closely mirrors my own, but only applies to a European audience.



Ah, that’s fair. Yeah, it’s basically the same question although I’m sure consumer protection laws vary widely.
